# Pandas how to combine rows groupby name by getting value='yes' in any row per column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to combine rows with column "name" and the table has different columns with value 'yes' in certain rows as follows,

below template gives the input and expected output:

```
name    department  feature1    feature2    feature3
x1         cs                      yes        yes
x1         cs         yes       
x1         ec           
x2         cs         yes          yes
x2         ec                      yes
```

Output i need to get is:

```
x1         cs        yes            yes       yes
x1         ec           
x2         cs        yes            yes
x2         ec                       yes
```

Suggestions please using python and pandas.

Comment: Are you guaranteed for the `yes`s not to be overlapping, then you can just: `df.groupby(['name', 'department']).sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#if want filter only `yes` values 
cols = df.columns.difference(['name','department'])
df[cols] = df[cols] == 'yes'
print (df)
  name department  feature1  feature2  feature3
0   x1         cs     False      True      True
1   x1         cs      True     False     False
2   x1         ec     False     False     False
3   x2         cs      True      True     False
4   x2         ec     False      True     False
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) and last [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `dict`:

```
df= df.groupby(['name','department']) \
      .max() \
      .replace({True:'yes',False:np.nan}) \
      .reset_index()

print (df)
  name department feature1 feature2 feature3
0   x1         cs      yes      yes      yes
1   x1         ec      NaN      NaN      NaN
2   x2         cs      yes      yes      NaN
3   x2         ec      NaN      yes      NaN
```

Thank you for comment, [AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396562/pandas-how-to-combine-rows-groupby-name-by-getting-value-yes-in-any-row-per-co#comment77754066_45396606), there also can be used [`DataFrameGroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html):

```
df= df.groupby(['name','department']) \
      .any() \
      .replace({True:'yes',False:np.nan}) \
      .reset_index()

print (df)
  name department feature1 feature2 feature3
0   x1         cs      yes      yes      yes
1   x1         ec      NaN      NaN      NaN
2   x2         cs      yes      yes      NaN
3   x2         ec      NaN      yes      NaN
```

Also works if all values are only `yes` and `NaN`s:

```
df = df.fillna('').groupby(['name', 'department']).max().reset_index()
print (df)
  name department feature1 feature2 feature3
0   x1         cs      yes      yes      yes
1   x1         ec                           
2   x2         cs      yes      yes         
3   x2         ec               yes
```

EDIT:

You can create custom `dict` by `dict comprehension` with aggregate functions and use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = {'feature3': ['yes', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
     'feature2': ['yes', np.nan, np.nan, 'yes', 'yes'], 
     'name': ['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2'], 
     'count': [10.0, 30.0, np.nan, 20.0, 3.0],
     'feature1': [np.nan, 'yes', np.nan, 'yes', np.nan], 
     'department': ['cs', 'cs', 'ec', 'cs', 'ec'], 
     'description': ['xsdepartment1', 'xsdepartment2', np.nan, 'department1', 'department3']}

c = ['name','department','feature1','feature2','feature3','count','description']
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = c)
print (df)
  name department feature1 feature2 feature3  count    description
0   x1         cs      NaN      yes      yes   10.0  xsdepartment1
1   x1         cs      yes      NaN      NaN   30.0  xsdepartment2
2   x1         ec      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN            NaN
3   x2         cs      yes      yes      NaN   20.0    department1
4   x2         ec      NaN      yes      NaN    3.0    department3

cols = df.columns.difference(['name','department','count','description'])

f = lambda x: tuple(x)
d = {x:'max' for x in cols}
d['count'] = f
d['description'] = f
print (d)
{'feature3': 'max', 
'feature1': 'max', 
'feature2': 'max', 
'description': <function <lambda> at 0x000000000F6FC598>, 
'count': <function <lambda> at 0x000000000F6FC598>}
```

---

```
df[cols] = df[cols] == 'yes'
print (df)
  name department  feature1  feature2  feature3  count    description
0   x1         cs     False      True      True   10.0  xsdepartment1
1   x1         cs      True     False     False   30.0  xsdepartment2
2   x1         ec     False     False     False    NaN            NaN
3   x2         cs      True      True     False   20.0    department1
4   x2         ec     False      True     False    3.0    department3

df = df.groupby(['name', 'department']).agg(d).reset_index()
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({True:'yes',False:np.nan})
print (df)
  name department feature3 feature1 feature2                     description  \
0   x1         cs      yes      yes      yes  (xsdepartment1, xsdepartment2)   
1   x1         ec      NaN      NaN      NaN                          (nan,)   
2   x2         cs      NaN      yes      yes                  (department1,)   
3   x2         ec      NaN      NaN      yes                  (department3,)   

          count  
0  (10.0, 30.0)  
1        (nan,)  
2       (20.0,)  
3        (3.0,)
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `.any()` instead of `.max()` (first example)? Seems more appropriate for bool types and presumably short-circuits. Note: `.any()` would work with the original data without any mapping.

Comment: @AChampion - you are rigth, there can be used `any` too. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Bonifacio2,  jezrael, @AChampion for the prompt response. I tried the suggested options and it worked like charm.  in need to add one more comment to the original question. I have some more columns and those column values i need to maintain

Comment: @sri - There is more columns which need process another way? Can you explain more?

Comment: name    department  feature1    feature2    feature3  count
x1         cs                                   yes        yes              10
x1         cs                 yes       
x1         ec           
x2         cs                yes          yes
x2         ec                                yes                               20

Comment: Hmmm, so they is column `count`. Do you need sum values per groups? Or mean? There are more columns like count (non feature)?

Comment: i have some more columns like  count, description and i need to retain those values as below.                                                             
[table] name department feature1 feature2 feature3 count  description
x1 cs  yes yes 10 xsdepartment
x1 cs yes    xsdepartment
x1 ec     
x2 cs yes  yes  csdepartment
x2 ec  yes  20 ecdepartment
      
And output should be      
x1 cs yes yes yes 10 xsdepartment
x1 ec     
x2 cs yes  yes  csdepartment
x2 ec  yes  20 ecdepartment

Comment: @jezrael, sorry for the poor formatting. i just need to retain the values as such for column count and description.

Comment: @sri - Hmmmm, but you aggregate data - e.g. from first 2 rows (x1, cs) need one row. So if count in first rows is 10 and secon 20, what is one output aggregate value? And if `xsdepartment` and `csdepartment` then need `xsdepartment, csdepartment` (one aggregate value) ?

Comment: Or there is also same value `10` and `10` and `xsdepartment` and `xsdepartment ` for same `name` and `department` ?

Comment: I think if `d = {'feature3': ['yes', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
     'feature2': ['yes', np.nan, np.nan, 'yes', 'yes'], 
     'name': ['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2'], 
     'count': [10.0, 30.0, np.nan, 20.0, 3.0],
     'feature1': [np.nan, 'yes', np.nan, 'yes', np.nan], 
     'department': ['cs', 'cs', 'ec', 'cs', 'ec'], 
     'description': ['xsdepartment1', 'xsdepartment2', np.nan, 'department1', 'department3']}

c = ['name','department','feature1','feature2','feature3','count','description']
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = c)
print (df)` what is desired output?

Comment: Alo there are only 3 feature columns with only `yes` and `NaN` values?

Comment: Can you create similar output `df` like 2 coment above? I am the most interested about first aggregate row. Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael, Thanks for pointing me to the question, for count and description columns i need to maintain a list of values. like first row should look like [x1, cs, yes, yes, yes, [10, 20], ['xsdepartment1', 'xsdepartment2']]

Comment: Thanks. how many there is features columns in real data? Only 3?

Comment: Yes, its 3 columns, but if columns increase i might need to handle it accordingly.

Comment: list causes a bit problems (`ValueError: Function does not reduce`). Is possible convert to `tuples` instead `lists` ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, tuples is also fine, i can modify internally to lists.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael appreciate your extended help, i will accept your answer.